# class returns an empty page when pressed back button

Tags: android, android-intent

I called an intent from the class but on pressing back key it gives a blank screen. i want it to return to the previous list activity this class had been called from.
my class is

```
package com.chirag.ipuconnect;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class GTBIT extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String namaste="http://www.gtbit.org/";
        Intent dex=new Intent(GTBIT.this,MainActivity.class);
        dex.putExtra("url", namaste);
        startActivity(dex);

    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a finish() after startActivity(dex).

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the content in this Activity

```
 setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
```

Or what You want to do with this Activity shown above? Is there a reason why You haven´t done this?

Comment: this activity calls my browser but all i want it do is after my browser is called and back button is pressed to get out of the browser i want it to return to the list this clas was called from and not return an empty page

Answer (score 0):

public void onBackPressed()
{

//your code is here

}